# Symfony2 and RabbitMqBundle. Can't publish a message

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I am trying to use syfmony2 framework with [RabbitMqBundle from here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle)

I am sure that my rabbitmq server is up and running and I am doing the configuration and publishers code accordingly to the docs delivered on github. Unfortunately I can`t add any message to the queue.

I am sure that my rabbitmq server is up and running. I have queue named accordingly to the symfony configuration file.

Have anyone got any clue what is wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well... try this simple example

```php
# app/config.yml
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections: %rabbitmq_connections%
    producers: %rabbitmq_producers%
    consumers: %rabbitmq_consumers%

parameters:
    # connection parameters
    rabbitmq_connections:
        default: { host: 'localhost', port: 5672, user: 'guest', password: 'guest', vhost: '/' }

    # define producers
    rabbitmq_producers:
        sample:
            connection:         default
            exchange_options:   {name: 'exchange_name', type: direct, auto_delete: false, durable: true}

    # define consumers
    rabbitmq_consumers:
        sample:
            connection:         default
            exchange_options:   {name: 'exchange_name', type: direct, auto_delete: false, durable: true}
            queue_options:      {name: 'sample', auto_delete: false}
            callback:           rabbitmq.callback.service
```

then you should define your callback service. feel free to put it in `app/config.yml`

```yml
services:
    rabbitmq.callback.service:
        class: RabbitMQ\Callback\Service
```

and yes. you should write this callback service. here is simple implementation. should be enough for understanding and check is it works for you.

```php
namespace RabbitMQ\Callback;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
use PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class Service implements ConsumerInterface 
{
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        var_dump(unserialize($msg->body));
    }
}
```

then you should start rabbitmq server, run consumer and check was new exchange and queue added.
to run test consumer  you should run

```sh
app/console rabbitmq:consumer sample --route="sample"
```

in your controller (where you want to send message to rabbitMQ put next code

```php
# get producer service
$producer = $this->get('old_sound_rabbit_mq.sample_producer');
# publish message
$producer->publish(serialize(array('foo'=>'bar','_FOO'=>'_BAR')), 'sample');
```

Hope it's more or less clear and will help you with rabbitmq.

PS: it's easier to debug if you have rabbitmq management plugin. if you have no, use console commands like `rabbitmqctl` to check queues/exchanges/consumers and so on...

and also would be nice to see your configuration for producers/consumers. callback services code as well.

Comment: Everything was fine in my code but I had to run consumer for a while and then all went fine. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issue to send messages with this bundle, i recommend you to try [SonataNotificationBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNotificationBundle) instead.

You can also install the [RabbitMq management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) to see the queued messages.

Comment: And I would like to end up with working bundle mentioned in the question :) But thanks for reply anyway